# java swing progress bar not displayed

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

I am trying to display an indeterminate progress bar when the user clicks certain buttons in my swing app. I have written a generic class for the progress bar that  am simply calling everytime those few buttons are clicked. The progress bar window is shown in the taskbar but not on the screen. Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

SSCE for my application: Progress Bar class

```
package mainform;

public class ProgressBarIndeterminate extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public ProgressBarIndeterminate() {
    initComponents();
}


private void initComponents() {

    jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    setUndecorated(true);
    setResizable(false);

    jProgressBar1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jProgressBar1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 0));
    jProgressBar1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
    jProgressBar1.setFocusable(false);
    jProgressBar1.setIndeterminate(true);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 171, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );

    pack();
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ProgressBarIndeterminate().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}                        
private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
}
```

Class ViewRec:

```
package mainform;
public class ViewRec extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public ViewRec() {
    initComponents();
    try{
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}  

private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    setResizable(false);

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "E-Mail ID", "Customer Name", "City", "State", "Industry", "Priority"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, false, false, false
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 912, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}                            
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;    
}
```

Class ComposeMail:

```
package mainform;
public class ComposeMail extends javax.swing.JFrame {
ProgressBarIndeterminate pbi=new ProgressBarIndeterminate();

public ComposeMail() {                
        initComponents();            
}


private void initComponents() {

    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton4.setText("View Recipients");
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()

                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
    ))))));
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(11, 11, 11)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(3, 3, 3)                        
                .addComponent(jButton4))                
    )));
    pack();
}

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    pbi.setVisible(true);
    new ViewRec().setVisible(true);
    pbi.dispose();
}                                        
public static void main(String[] args){        
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ComposeMail().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;             
}
```

Compile and run ComposeMail to recreate my issue.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I just tried it with Windows 7 & Java 6 (had to remove `setType()` and the catch clause with multiple exceptions) and it worked.

How much time takes `/*DO SOME WORK*/`?

Comment: I observed the same behaviour too

Comment: I can't see where the progress bar is added to the frame/layout.

Comment: I take back my earlier comment. Jumped the gun too quickly. I don't see any problem with Java 7 either. It depends on how long the task `/*DO SOME WORK*/` takes, as the progress bar will be disposed as soon as that work completes

Comment: @stuXnet I am working on Win7 with Java 7. For most of these tasks the time is variable since database connections are being set up. But on average it takes about 6-10 seconds.

Comment: @stuXnet I removed `setType()` and also the catch clause in `main()`. But the progress bar still doesn't show.

Comment: @BinoyDalal could you try to provide us a SSCCE? Delete every line that isn't necessary to reproduce your problem (i.e. setting background color) and minimal example for your "main" frame. Maybe just sleep after clicking the button. For further info: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @stuXnet Please check the edit I have made.

Comment: @BinoyDalal your problem is a threading one - see my answer. And please take a closer look to sscce.org, there are still many unnecessary lines in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your progress bar would be shown - if only Swing were thread safe.

Remove pbi.dispose(), and you should see your progress bar.

You are setting it visible, but immediately afterwards you create an instance of ViewRec - and ViewRec is going to block the thread for it's actions. After ViewRec is constructed, setVisible() is going to be called, and again immediately, you dispose your progress bar.

You can find information about how to use progress bars in the [official Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) offered by Oracle.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks. Will take a closer look at the SSCE. Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! The thing with the SSCCE is: when trying to reduce your code to the minimum, chances are high that you are able to see the problem by yourself. And even if not, you have a much better foundation to ask questions: "My progress bar doesn't work, look at it" could become to "Why is my progress bar immediately hidden again after loading another window?"
And it's also easier for people to help you, because they can quickly see if it's an problem they could solve.